# TCP TIME_WAIT problem

Tags: sockets, tcp, ip, time-wait

I have read a TCP and socket programming book. I have a question,

The TIME_WAIT state of the TCP should remain 2MSL time period as 
the book said. But how then a internet explore like application
does not have this problem?

According to the documentation, it's 4 minutes , but in Internet explore
I don't have to wait even 10 seconds to refresh a web page?

How this works? I'm confused please explain.

Comment: Even though I'm waiting for my daughter to call, I can still watch television, read a book, or take a nap. Waiting for something doesn't mean you can't do anything else.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few possibilities, some of which I've listed below.

The first is that not all sessions move through the `TIME_WAIT` state at all. If the other side closes the connection, the local transitions are `ESTABLISHED`, `CLOSE_WAIT`, `LAST_ACK` and `CLOSED`, so there's no `TIME_WAIT` involved.

Secondly, the `TIME_WAIT` state applies to a *session,* which is a 5-tuple `{protocol,source-ip,source-port,dest-ip,dest-port}`.

If *any* of those values change for the next session (usually source-port), that's unaffected by the previous session.

Lastly, the browser doesn't *have* to shut down the session after each request. It's more likely (for efficiency) to maintain a pool of open sessions in order to re-use them, such as when you want to download a page with fifty images (one session rather than fifty one).

It can even leave such sessions open after a page is fully loaded, on the off-chance you'll access something else on that server.